# removing css hover effect of one link while keeping same hover effect for other links

Tags: html, css, hover

I have the following code in HTML:

```
        <div id="side">
            <ul class="sideCol sideCol-fixed">
                <li>
                    <div class="user-view" style="background-color: #141E30;">
                        <a href="https://hypotheticallink"><u><i><b>LINK TO EXTERNAL PAGE</b></i></u></a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <div class="steps">
                    <li><a href="/link1">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/link2">Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/link3">Link 3</a></li>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

and the following code in CSS:

```
#side li a:hover{
  color: black;
}
```

I only recently added in the line `<a href="https://hypotheticallink"><u><i><b>LINK TO EXTERNAL PAGE</b></i></u></a>` and previously I had set the css so that when the cursor hovers over Link 1, Link 2 and Link 3, the text turns black, where previously the text is white.

The text for the "LINK TO EXTERNAL PAGE" anchor tag is also initally white, but unlike the other links I do not want it to turn black when I hover on it. I have tried adding an id to the anchor tag (`<a id="newid" href="https://hypotheticallink"><u><i><b>LINK TO EXTERNAL PAGE</b></i></u></a>`), and then adding css to that id in the stylesheet (code at bottom of question) to make it so that the text turns white when hovered over (thus aiming to make it not turn black) but this does not work and the text still turns black. Would anyone know how to achieve this?

```
#newid:hover{
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Add .steps before the hover css .. then this hover effect will only apply to anchor tags inside the div with class steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selector that you tried to apply has lower css specificity.

Solution:
Use selector with higher specificity to override this style.

For example you can use:

```
.user-view > #newid:hover {
   color: white;
}
```

or

```
#side #newid:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

or

```
#side li .user-view a:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

Here: https://specificity.keegan.st/ you can calculate your selector specificity.

```
#side li a:hover{
  color: black;
}
```

Has specificity 1.1.2 where,

```
#newid:hover{
  color: white;
}
```

Has specificity 1.1.0 so this style in other words, was less important and thus not applied.

Here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity you can read more about it.

Comment: I've edited the question to show the css I've used to make the last 3 links turn black, I've tested it in your jsfiddle link and now the external link (first one) also turns black

Comment: I see the problem now. It is rooted in css specificity. #side li a:hover selector overrides #newid:hover selector. To overcome that use for example:
.user-view > #newid:hover{
  color: white;
}

Comment: thank you, this worked. I noticed that if I use class instead of id (and change the # to .) this doesn't work - how would I do this with class?

Comment: Check this new fiddle it uses class now https://jsfiddle.net/to2fga1w/2/, is that answering your question?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to add a css class instead?

```
<div id="side">
    <ul class="sideCol sideCol-fixed">
        <li>
            <div class="user-view" style="background-color: #141E30;">
                <a class="externallink" href="https://hypotheticallink"><u><i><b>LINK TO EXTERNAL PAGE</b></i></u></a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <div class="steps">
            <li><a href="/link1">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="/link2">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="/link3">Link 3</a></li>
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.externallink:hover{
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this to select you list item

```
<div id="side">
        <ul class="sideCol sideCol-fixed">
            <li>
                <div class="user-view" style="background-color: #141E30;">
                    <a href="https://hypotheticallink"><u><i><b>LINK TO EXTERNAL PAGE</b></i></u></a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <div class="steps">
                <li><a href="/link1">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="/link2">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="/link3">Link 3</a></li>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.steps :hover { 
     /* your css code here */
     color:black;
  }
```